# Error when checking input: expected embedding_Embedding1_input to have shape [,1103], but got array with shape [1103,1]

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, tensorflow.js

To learn about Tensorflow.js for future projects, I am attempting to work off of [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/automatically-generate-hotel-descriptions-with-lstm-afa37002d4fc) while also converting the examples from Python to NodeJS. Part of it is to generate training data by creating training sets with predictor inputs and label outputs. I can't see how my training sets are the wrong shape for these layers.

The model creation looks like this:

```
model = tf.sequential();
model.add( tf.layers.embedding( {
    inputDim: total_words + 1,
    outputDim: 10,
    inputLength: max_length,
} ) );
model.add( tf.layers.lstm( {
    units: 100,
    kernelRegularizer: tf.regularizers.l2( {
        l2: 0.0001
    } )
} ) );
model.add( tf.layers.dropout( {
    rate: 0.1
} ) );
model.add( tf.layers.dense( { units: total_words, activation: 'softmax' } ) );
const optimizer = tf.train.rmsprop( learningRate );
model.compile( { optimizer: optimizer, loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy' } );
```

And the training loop looks like this:

```
for ( let i = 0; i < sets.length; ++i ) {
    let predictor = tf.tensor1d( sets[ i ].predictor );
    let label = tf.scalar( sets[ i ].label );
    await model.fit( predictor, label, {
        epochs: epochs,
        callbacks
    } );
    predictor.dispose();
    label.dispose();
}
```

In case anyone asks about how I generate the training sets:

```
async function GenerateTrainingSets( paddedInputSequence, maxInput ) {
    let sets = [];
    for ( let i = 0; i < maxInput - 1; i++ ) {
        let predArray = [];
        for ( let preds = 0; preds < sets.length + 1; preds++ ) {
            predArray.push( paddedInputSequence[ preds ] );
        }
        let sizeDifference = maxInput - predArray.length;
        for ( let pads = 0; pads < sizeDifference; pads++ ) {
            predArray.push( 0 );
        }
        sets.push( {
            predictor: predArray,
            label: paddedInputSequence[ i + 1 ]
        } )
    }
    return sets;
}
```

The predictors are 1d arrays of the same length (1103) and labels are scalars (ints).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is expecting input of shape `[null, total_words + 1]` (null is for the batchsize). The input should be at least a 2d tensor. If it is not (1d tensor), it is expanded on the axis -1.

The input tensor can be expanded on the axis 0, if you want to predict from a single vector.

```js
let predictor = tf.tensor2d( sets[ i ].predictor, [1, total_words + 1] ); // total_words + 1 should be 1103
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Seems that I made both the predictors and labels one rank too low and the next error I had after I fixed this was about the labels. Interesting that this particular error was very vague but the label error specifically mentioned that it was expecting a 1d tensor but got a scalar which is obviously easier to understand.